# Inner Join with linq and razor

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have 2 tables, PostThr and PostEig. PostThr has the job date of service, and PostEig has the available worker slots for the job.

I want to show a list of upcoming jobs, and under each job, the available worker slots.
How could I do this?

From what I understand, I should write a linq query, but I'm not sure how to write the query. I can write the query for each table separately, below. In sql I would write it as a join of sorts. And then, once I have the data, I can show them in a foreach loop on the razor page.

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
var jobs = _context.PostThrs.Where(m => m.ThrDate > today
                && m.ThrText == "SERVICE DATE");

//zero is the FK...
var zero = "2102-01";
var slots = _context.PostEigs.Where(m => m.EigZero == zero
                && m.EigAgen == "OPEN");
```

The 2 tables are as follows:

```
Table PostThr
    ThrId | ZeroId | ThrDate | ThrText

Table PostEig
    EigId | ZeroId | EigAgen | EigLoad
```

update

Master Zero Table

```
public class PostZero
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Display(Name = "0/")]
    public string Zero { get; set; }
}
```

PostThr Table

```
public class PostThr
{
[Key]
    public int ThrId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostZero")]
    public string ThrZero { get; set; }

    public int ThrDigit { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ThrDate { get; set; }

    public string ThrTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ThrText { get; set; }
}
```

PostEig Table

```
public class PostEig
{
    [Key]
    public int EigId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostZero")]
    public string EigZero { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Number")]
    public int EigDigit { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EigAgen { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EigRole { get; set; }

    public string EigCont { get; set; }

    public decimal EigLoad { get; set; }

    public string EigNote { get; set; }
}
```

updated with VM

```
public class AgentClientIndexVM
{
    public string Zero { get; set; }

    public DateTime ThrDate { get; set; }

    public string ThrTime { get; set; }

    public string ThrText { get; set; }

    public string EigAgen { get; set; }

    public string EigRole { get; set; }

    public decimal EigLoad { get; set; }

    public string EigNote { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Add your entities classes and answer will appear immediately.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv is that what you meant? sorry, I don't have a lot of experience

Comment: Classes, not structure. Everything counts, type of properties, navigation properties.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv updated with the models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly tables are connected via `PostZero`

```cs
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
var jobs = 
   from h in _context.PostThrs
   join e in _context.PostEigs on h.ThrZero equals e.EigZero
   where h.ThrDate > today && h.ThrText == "SERVICE DATE"
      && e.EigAgen == "OPEN"
   select new AgentClientIndexVM
   {
       Zero = h.ThrZero,
       ThrDate = h.ThrDate,
       ThrTime = h.ThrTime,
       ThrText = h.ThrText,
       EigAgen = e.EigAgen,
       EigRole = e.EigRole,
       EigLoad = e.EigLoad,
       EigNote = e.EigNote    
   };
```

Comment: And then "return View(jobs);", will drive it to the view, correct?

Comment: Yes, but `H = h` is just my considerations how result model should looks like. If you provide result class, answer will be more precise.

Comment: updated with the VM. I should use the PostEig key as primary?

Comment: Great. I can see how it all fits. My problem now is displaying it in the razor view. I was going to use "@foreach (var item in Model)" but this doesn't work. I appreciate your help thus far, however, and would agree that you answered my initial question

Comment: Probably adding `jobs.ToList()` will solve your problem.

Comment: Where should I put that?

Comment: Can you please advise where to place "jobs.ToList()" ?